# Contract job that doesn't allow taking personal credit for the work

Tags: contracts, freelancing, portfolio

I was offered a contract job to write some mobile code for a company but was told I could take no credit for it (could not put it in my portfolio, resume, etc. I would also have to sign an NDA). Is this a red flag or is it normal in the programming business? I asked for a day to consult my friends to see if it was a good idea or not.

I got the offer because I know someone that works at the company. I don't think there would be a problem with payment. I've never done contract work before so I'm not sure if this is normal or not.

Comment: This is not an answer, but: make sure you have *something* you can say to explain the gap to a future employer. "Worked on a stealth-mode project in the ______ industry, April 2017 - December 2017" or something. Check with the employer to see how specific you can get.

Comment: Thanks I didn't mean credit in terms of wanting my name in the app or being publicly recognized for it. I presumed most contracts would allow me to put on my resume or website that I worked on the project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is not a red flag.  In my years as a consultant, some companies ask for confidentiality in this area, and others don't.  On your resume, you can list this as *Confidential Client* and describe it as a *Confidential Project*.

If the project is interesting to you, and you agree on payment terms, I would have no reservations with this arrangement.  ( No credit taken / signing an NDA )

Comment: Perfect answer. In 20 years as a contractor, I've never once asked for a credit; I do the job for money, not ego. We act as 'white-label' suppliers to anyone that wants to pay us.

Comment: Typically I throw on the resume: "Job Suchandsuch - Worked on a variety of internal projects, using skills such as ___" with no reference to how those skills were applied in particular.

Comment: @SliderBlackrose That's a good approach too!  Seen it both ways.

Comment: @PeteCon - What do you do for a job looking for experience and the only time you've worked in that area was in a confidential project?

Comment: @JeffO, "Independent Contractor, Confidential Client (Fortune 50), Confidential Project" then you describe your experience without driving into the specific company or project you did it on.

Comment: @ChrisG - Would it be common for them to prevent you from indicating what technology you're working with? What if they don't want the competition to know what database they use? I've never been in this situation.

Comment: @JeffO If your client is confidential, and the project is confidential, then knowing that you worked with a particular technology isn't a problem (generally, a specific NDA may lay out specific rules).